# Intalling Headphones or LazyLibrarian on windows

Tags: windows-xp, python

I have winxp sp 3, python 3.2, git.

I have tried many times to install and run in windows.

But i keep getting Deamonize errors.

My plan is once these run 100%, to run these as windows services.

Some of these python apps are not likely to be updated any time soon.

Any suggestions or alternative python apps?

Answer (score 1):

Try python 2.7. Those apps are not written for 3, and in most cases it requires major rewrites, you will find this with most python applications.